# load html from asset by html javascript button click on android webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

I want to load to a home.html page inside asset folder by clicking a button in index.html inside android webview.

heres the code:

Javascript:

```
<script>
        function home() {
            location.href = "home.html";
        }
</script>
```

Button:

```
<button onclick="home()">Home</button>
```

Java:

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

But the problem is when i click on button it opens WPS OFFICE and toast's a message:

The file must has been renamed, moved or deleted.

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This will solve your problem.